# UrbanAirship activity issue in manifest in eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse, urbanairship.com

here is my code of manifest, in which i am getting error at  android:resource="@layout/ua_activity_landing_page". Code is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen"
android:versionCode="14"
android:versionName="1.4" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<!-- Permission to get DeviceId -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. NOTE: the permission *must* be called PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE,
    where PACKAGE is the application's package name.-->
<permission
    android:name="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- GCM requires Android SDK version 2.2 (API level 8) or above. -->
<!--
  The targetSdkVersion is optional, but it's always a good practice
  to target higher versions.
-->
<permission
    android:name="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen.permission.UA_DATA"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen.permission.UA_DATA" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

<application
    android:name="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen.MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen.MESSAGE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen.Catagories"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen.Catagory_Detailed"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen.PurchaseWalls"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen.RK"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen.Home"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!-- LSM -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.lifestreet.android.lsmsdk.ads.InterstitialAdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.lifestreet.android.lsmsdk.mraid.MRAIDInterstitialActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.lifestreet.android.lsmsdk.VideoPlayerActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.tenjin.android.TenjinReferrerReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- REQUIRED for Urban Airship Push -->
    <activity android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreActivity" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="-999" >
            <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.OPENED" />

            <category android:name="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.LandingPageActivity"
        android:exported="false" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.urbanairship.action.LANDING_PAGE_VIEW"
            android:resource="@layout/ua_activity_landing_page" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.urbanairship.push.iam.EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_SHOW"
            android:value="true" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.SHOW_LANDING_PAGE_INTENT_ACTION" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="message" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- REQUIRED for Urban Airship -->
    <service
        android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushService"
        android:label="Push Notification Service" />

    <!-- Required for analytics -->
    <service
        android:name="com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService"
        android:label="Event Service" />

    <!-- Required for Actions -->
    <service android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.ActionService" />

    <!-- Required for Rich Push -->
    <service android:name="com.urbanairship.richpush.RichPushUpdateService" />

    <!-- REQUIRED for GCM -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- OPTIONAL, if you want to receive push, push opened and registration completed intents -->
    <!-- Replace the receiver below with your package and class name -->
    <receiver
        android:name="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen.IntentReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.CHANNEL_UPDATED" />
            <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.OPENED" />
            <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.DISMISSED" />
            <action android:name="com.urbanairship.push.RECEIVED" />

            <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Use your package name as the category -->
            <category android:name="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- This is required for persisting preferences related to push and location -->
    <provider
        android:name="com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider"
        android:authorities="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen.urbanairship.provider"
        android:exported="true"
        android:multiprocess="true"
        android:permission="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen.permission.UA_DATA" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.calldorado.android.actionreceiver.ActionReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <action android:name="com.calldorado.android.intent.SEND_RATING_REQ" />
            <action android:name="com.calldorado.android.intent.SEARCH" />
            <action android:name="com.calldorado.android.intent.INITSDK" />
            <action android:name="com.calldorado.android.intent.COMM_END" />
            <action android:name="com.calldorado.android.intent.WIC_POSITION" />
            <action android:name="com.calldorado.android.intent.MAKE_CALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="com.calldorado.android.intent.TRIGGER_SEND" />
            <action android:name="com.calldorado.android.intent.PACEMAKER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="com.calldorado.android.intent.DYNAMIC_RE_ENGAGEMENT" />
            <action android:name="com.calldorado.android.intent.PRIORITY" />
            <action android:name="com.calldorado.android.intent.HEARTBEAT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />

            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.calldorado.analytics.CalldoradoStatsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.calldorado.android.ui.ResultActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.calldorado.android.ui.AfterCallActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.calldorado.android.ui.SettingsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <data android:scheme="rkp.free.biblefy.your.screen.settingsactivity" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.calldorado.android.service.CalldoradoCommunicationService" />
    <service android:name="com.calldorado.android.ad.BannerLoadingService" />
    <service android:name="com.calldorado.android.GoogleSyncService" />
    <service android:name="com.calldorado.analytics.CalldoradoStatsCommunicationService" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.calldorado.AccountId"
        android:value="a1-dfa69600-4598-49fb-9db9-26ce8053a220" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.calldorado.AppId"
        android:value="b0-ccc4d694-7994-426a-84eb-ab11103bbf8c" />
</application>
```

Please help me with the ua_activity_landing_page layout code, since i don't have so much knowledge of android and specially of eclipse android !!!

Comment: show that activity_landing_page

Comment: You should include in your question: 1) what you want `ua_activity_landing_page` to do 2) what you tried to achieve to achieve that, including code.

Comment: @user5226582 i want the landing page to open the app and show a screen to load items in background.

Comment: @ManojFrekzz i haven't coded that activity yet so can't  show

Comment: You should use setContentView to set the layout, not the meta-data to set the layout.

Comment: @ManojFrekzz can you please tell me what exactly a landing page is user her for, as this is an unfinished project of someoneelse which i have to complete. So I need some help out!!

Comment: Landing page is an activity, it holds an UI, that ls  'ua_activity_landing_page' , here the meta-data tag holds the resource which is used by that activity.

Comment: @ManojFrekzz so can i use the mainactivity here insted of ua_activity_landing_page??

Comment: What are you saying, the MainActivity contains a different UI, and that corresponding activity consists of the methods to handle that UI. So as Landing Activity. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127803/discussion-between-ananya-srivastav-and-manoj-frekzz).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what SDK version you are trying to use but the problem is missing resources. You can go ahead and remove the metadata entry in the manifest:

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.urbanairship.action.LANDING_PAGE_VIEW"
            android:resource="@layout/ua_activity_landing_page" />
```

The landing page activity will fallback to generating a layout programatically.

This seems like a bigger issue with your set up. It seems resources are unavailable in your project, so your project is probably not set up properly for Urban Airship. Make sure its set up as a resource android library project. Eclipse is no longer supported so I would strongly recommend converting the project to use Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @ralepinski